# How can I check login and password editexts

Tags: android

Hello I want to check login and password editexts before inserting them in the databse. I used this code. It checks the login very well and if the password or the password2 are empty it display the message (entre 4 et 20 caractères) and it doesn't insert them in the database. So it display the message (Echec) but when the passwod and password2 are differents it display the message (Mots de passe ne correspondent pas) but it insert data in the database

```
if (!validate()) {
            onSignupFailed();
            return;
        }
```

how can I prohibit the insertion if the two passwords do not match?

```
public void onSignupFailed() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Echec", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public boolean validate() {
        boolean valid = true;
        String login = et_login.getText().toString();
        String password = et_password.getText().toString();
        String password2 = et_password2.getText().toString();
        if (login.isEmpty() || login.length() < 3) {
            et_login.setError("entrer un login valide");
            valid = false;
        } else {
            et_login.setError(null);
        }
        if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 20 || password2.isEmpty() || password2.length() < 4 || password2.length() > 20) {
            et_password.setError("entre 4 et 20 caractères");
            valid = false;
        }else if(!password2.equals(password)){
            et_password2.setError("Mots de passe ne correspondent pas");
        }
        else{
            et_password2.setError(null);
        }
        return valid;
    }
```

Comment: Quite a silly question in my opinion. Simply setting valid to false if they don't match will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it, you put the value `true` on the boolean `valid` if you want to make the insertion, but `false` if an error happens.

Why don't you put it to `false` when the passwords are different?

```
//Some code
} else if (!password2.equals(password)){
        et_password2.setError("Mots de passe ne correspondent pas");
        valid = false;
}
```